# Determinants and homomorphisms of general linear groups

Tags: group-theory, determinant

Consider the functions $\rho_1:M_1(\mathbb C)\to M_2(\mathbb R)$ where
$$\rho_1(a+bi)=\begin{pmatrix} a&b\\ -b&a \end{pmatrix}$$ and $\rho_2:M_2(\mathbb C)\to M_4(\mathbb R)$ where
$$\rho_2\begin{pmatrix} a+bi&c+di\\ e+fi&h+ji \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} a&b&c&d \\ -b&a&-d&c \\ e&f&h&j \\ -f&e&-j&h \end{pmatrix}$$
This can be generalized to functions $\rho_n:M_n(\mathbb C)\to M_{2n}(\mathbb R)$.

If $A\in GL_n(\mathbb C)$ then $\rho_n(A)\in GL_{2n}(\mathbb R)$ and we know $\det(A)\neq 0$ and $\det(\rho_n(A))\neq 0$.

In that situation is there anything more precise that can be stated about $\det(A)$ and $\det(\rho_n(A))$ beyond  both of them being nonzero?

Comment: The case $n = 1$ suggests a conjecture. Can you prove it? (Hint: it suffices to prove it for diagonal matrices by continuity.)

Comment: $\det(\rho_nA)=\det(A')$ where $A'=(|a_{ij}|^2)$ if $A=(a_{ij})$

Comment: No. The right conjecture is $\det(\rho_n A) = |\det(A)|^2$.